# Open CMD box in C and hide pop up

Tags: winapi, dos

Hello all I was wondering if someone could help me with this issue I am calling a cmd prompt .exe file from within my WINAPI project. This works ok however the black dos box pops up for a split second. Its not the end of the world but i was messing around trying to block it.

This code works fine but the box pops up which I use to call the .exe and save the data.

```
system("my.exe > output.txt");
```

This is my other work around using winexec

```
WinExec("my.exe > output.txt",SW_SHOWMINIMIZED); // This wont work
```

This will work

```
WinExec("my.exe",SW_SHOWMINIMIZED); // This will work but I cant add the  > output.txt to save my output.
```

Any recommendations please ?

BR

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to start your new process, and redirect standard out to a file handle. MSDN provides a sample that does just this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info found a simpler version here for anyone who is interested http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682512(VS.85).aspx this works but wont save the output into the .txt file. I mess around some more anyway BR.

Comment: fixed it the output for this file is batch.exe "my.exe -flags" otherwise will fail. Thanks matt